# Python - nested for loops and index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm rather new to Python, and am running into the following error when using a nested for loop

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code

```
count = 0
count2 = 1
rlength = range(len(records))
for i in rlength:
    ex = records[count].id
    for bla in rlength:
        if re.search(ex, records[count2].id) != None:
            print records[count2].id
        count2 += 1
    count += 1
    count2 = count + 1
```

Edit:

Fixed with the following code

```
rlength = range(len(records))
for i in rlength:
    ex = records[i].id
    for bla in rlength:
        if bla + 1 < len(rlength) and re.search(ex, records[bla + 1].id) != None:
            print records[bla].id
```

Comment: I think here is problem records[count2].id), you are moving one step forward in it.

Comment: I think you have to change this line from if re.search(ex, records[count2].id) != None: to if count2 in records and re.search(ex, records[count2].id) != None:

Comment: count2 can go our of range. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: I don't think you need `count` and `count2` at all. You can just use `i` and `bla` instead and your for loops will always remain within the range.

Comment: Thanks, I think this has done the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I'm not sure you need the `count` and `count2` at all. I think you can just use the numbers generated by your loop. I suggest using `enumerate()` instead of `range(len())`.

```
for i1,rlength1 in enumerate(records):
    ex = rlength1.id
    for i2,rlength2 in enumerate(records):
        if re.search(ex, rlength2.id) != None:
            print rlength2.id
```

Comment: This has helped, although the reason I implemented counts was because I wanted to compare record x with x+1, x+2, ... rather than itself. But this has pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: @Thistle19 You can of course do something like `records[i]` and `records[i+1]`, `records[i+2]`, but if you do that you need to stop the loop before you go past it to avoid the `IndexError`, either by using something like `range(len(records)-2)` or by doing an `if i+1 == len(records): break`

Answer (score 0):

The loop should fail for `i=1`. Why ?
When `i=1, count2 = 2 (= count + 1, and count = 0+1 = 1)`
In the inner loop, `count2 goes from 2 to 2+len(records)-1-1` (since we increment after looking at the values) = `len(records)`
But there is no `records[len(records)]` (and an index out of bound is NOT equivalent to None in python !)